# ¿porque se puede ajustar el gas en web3?

Tags: blockchain, solidity

¿porque se puede ajustar el gas en web3 cual es su funcion? me refiero a esto la parte que dice gas y gasPrice

```
{
"jsonrpc":"2.0",
"method":"eth_sendTransaction",
"params":[
    {
        "from":"0xb60e8dd61c5d32be8058bb8eb970870f07233155",
        "to":"0xd46e8dd67c5d32be8058bb8eb970870f07244567",
        "gas":"0x76c0",
        "gasPrice":"0x9184e72a000",
        "value":"0x9184e72a",
        "data":"0xd46e8dd67c5d32be8d46e8dd67c5d32be8058bb8eb970870f072445675058bb8eb970870f072445675"
    }
],
"id":1
```

Comment: si no haces el [tour] y entendes como funciona el sitio, el mismo va a prohibirte hacer nuevas preguntas... tambien mira [ask]. tus preguntas tienen poco sentido, que es lo que buscaste al respecto y no entendes?

Comment: Corresponde revisar la documentación de Ethereum para entender qué representa el gas y el gas price. Ni siquiera es de solidity sino de ethereum. No parece un problema de programación :/

Comment: voy a abandonar stackoverflow, porque la verdad lo unico que recibo son criticas y eso me enoja, tambien pregunto en facebook y lo unico que hacen es mofarse y burlarce nadie quiere ayudar no piensan que otros podrian tener mis mismas dudas? >:( es bien dificil publicar a qui >:(

Comment: la pregunta es clara, pero si comprendo tu segundo comentario

Comment: Entiendo lo frustrante, pero también ponte en nuestro lugar. Acá el formato de las preguntas y respuestas es claro. El objetivo también. Mientras algo compila o algo corre, venimos y tratamos de ayudar con problemas de programación. Sin embargo, esta pregunta por ejemplo trata sobre detalles de funcionamiento de un blockchain específico y yo, que no tengo ni idea de ethereum, encontré respuestas a eso con sólo buscar. Entonces, si ves los enlaces que te compartieron en otros comentarios, verás que el plan es buscar respuestas concretas a preguntas de programación.

Comment: Para los voluntarios no es feliz cuando alguien no busca, no lo intenta y y quiere que alguien busque en su lugar. ¿Se entiende la idea? Revisa los enlaces que te comparte gbianchi para que veas por qué contrapreguntamos.

Comment: "encontré respuestas a eso con sólo buscar." yo he buscado pero no he conseguido nada, no estoy seguro de que debo buscar :'/

Comment: Yo busqué `solidity gasprice' (sólo usé la etiqueta que pusiste) y encontré una definición en negrita y cursiva de qué es el gas y el gasprice en ethereum. Es casi que la diferencia con bitcoin...

Comment: gracias ya aparece informacion

Comment: Por favor, aclara tu problema específico o proporciona detalles adicionales para resaltar exactamente lo que necesitas. Tal como está escrito, es difícil saber exactamente qué estás preguntando.

Answer (score -1, accepted):

El parametro gas permite fijar el limite de gas permitido para gastar.

Aveces la ejecucion de un programa consume una cantidad de gas mayor en diferentes condiciones.

Si limitas el gas, garantisas que en caso de que el contrato intente consumir demaciado gas la transaccion se cancele.

limitar el gas puede terminar en un error de ejecucion por falta de gas, y usar valores muy altos de gas puede resultar en gastos execivos.